# Index of a subfactor of a full $II_1$ factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

On pg. 151 of "Coxeter Graphs and Towers of Algebras" by F.M. Goodman, P. de la Harpe, and V.F.R. Jones (1989), it is stated that there is no known example of a *full* $II_1$ factor having a subfactor of index $4\cos^2(\pi/q)$, $q \neq 3,4,6$.  (*Full* means that the group of inner automorphisms is closed in the topology of pointwise strong convergence in the group of all automorphisms.  For example, the $II_1$ factor $W^*(PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}))$ is full.)  Is this statement still true, or has an example been found?